# LVS Configuration issue (Using piranha Tool) 

Tags: iptables, load-balancing, tcpip, ip-routing, lvs

I have configured LVS on cent os using piranha tool .I am  using vip of internal n/w as gateway for real server we have two NIC one having exteranl Ip and other for internal n/w which is on 192.168.3.0/24 network.

> But I am not able to connect from client it shows connection refused
>   error

. Please suggest iptables rules for private n public n/w to communicate. May be I am missing this . Iptables rules  that we have added  are :

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.3.0/24 --sport 5000 -j MASQUERADE
```

this is my ipconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:E8:F6:74:DA 
          inet addr:122.166.233.133  Bcast:122.166.233.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::200:e8ff:fef6:74da/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:9469972 (9.0 MiB)  TX bytes:19929308 (19.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2000

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:E8:F6:74:DA 
          inet addr:122.166.233.136  Bcast:122.166.233.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:20:14:F9:2D 
          inet addr:192.168.3.1  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:20ff:fe14:f92d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:123718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:148856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18738556 (17.8 MiB)  TX bytes:11697153 (11.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:60000400-600004ff

eth1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:20:14:F9:2D 
          inet addr:192.168.3.10  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:17 Memory:60000400-600004ff

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:76:6E:D1:D2 
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:21 Base address:0xa500
```

and ipvsadm -ln command

```
[root@abts-kk-static-133 ~]# ipvsadm -ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  122.166.233.136:5000 wlc
TCP  122.166.233.136:5004 wlc

lvs server routing table
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
122.166.233.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         122.166.233.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

real 1

real 2

we have configured various ports from 5000:5008 .

Do we need to this iptables for all ports?

Suggest me how should I solve this issue.

Comment: If anybody still needs more explanation regarding my question ,let me know.As I am new to lvs and iptables, so guide me if I am missing something.

Comment: let me know, if you have any difficulties regarding understanding my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to decide what type of LVS you want: NAT, TUN, or DR.

> [packet-forwarding-method]
>
> ```
>       -g, --gatewaying  Use gatewaying (direct routing). This is the default.
>
>       -i, --ipip  Use ipip encapsulation (tunneling).
>
>       -m, --masquerading  Use masquerading (network access translation, or NAT).
> ```

You appear to want NAT so you'll need -m options to ipvsadm for your real servers.

A test piranha config is available here:

http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/docs/ha/piranha.html

Rather than manually configuring the NAT with your own iptables rule, you let ipvsadm do the NAT for you.  Delete your iptables rule, and for that matter, delete the aliased interfaces you specify above ending in :1.  That will greatly simplify things and get you on the right track.

Make sure your default gw on your real servers in 192.168.3.1.  From the Director, try pinging each of your realservers and also try telnetting to the LVS port(s) which look to be 5000/5004.  If all that is working, go back to your client and try telnetting to 5000/5004 on your VIP.

Comment: From my googling, ancient descriptions of ipvsadm seem to imply that ipvsadm masquerading would show up in iptables nat.  On CentOS 7, that is *not* the case, and likely hasn't been for a while: it is apparently a separate table, not visible to "iptables -L -t nat"